# SQL Pivot Problem - multiple aggregates?

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I have the following data returned buy a simple SQL query. The Number of sites could change, but X,Y,Z are fixed (they are different types of accidents, and the data stored represents the number of occurances)

```
| Site | X | Y | Z |
--------------------
   A      1   2   3
   B      4   5   6
   C      7   8   9
```

I need to get it to the following format

```
| A | B | C |
--------------
   1   4   7
   2   5   8
   3   6   9
```

I have this so far

```
select * 
from Example
pivot 
(
Max(X)
for site in ([A],[B],[C])
) as p
```

But I think I need multiple aggregates (for X, Y and Z).

Here is a quick script to create the base data

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Example](
     [Site] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
     [X] [int] NOT NULL,
     [Y] [int] NOT NULL,
     [Z] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into Example(Site, X,Y,Z) Values ('A',1,2,3)
insert into Example(Site, X,Y,Z) Values ('B',4,5,6)
insert into Example(Site, X,Y,Z) Values ('C',7,8,9)
```

Any help really welcome as I am stuck!

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to UNPIVOT your data, before rePIVOTing it about the accident site - like so:

```
select * 
from Example
unpivot 
(
numbers 
for type in (x,y,z)
) as p
pivot 
(
Max(numbers)
for site in ([A],[B],[C])
) as q
```